# Need Help About Laravel Api

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have two  web Application that's work in different domaine , The first one is a Laravel web application like this

```
domaine1.com
```

and another web application that's built also with laravel

```
domaine2.com
```

and i have on the first application a dashboard like this ( `domaine1.com/dashboard`) , 
I want to add from this dashboard for example A books to the the web Application 2  , that's have it own database and tables ......
Please can someone tell me how can i do it ? 
i'm kind of Newbie on laravel , i think i should Use something like API ? or Something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route in your Application 2 routes.php to get the books
for example

```
Route::get('domaine2.com/books', 'BookController@getBooks');
```

In your BookController:

```
 public function getBooks()
    {
        $books = Books::all();    //I assume that Books is your model
        return $books
    }
```

Now all you have to do is call this in a function in your controller from domaine1.com application to have your books

```
$books = file_get_contents('http://domaine2.com/books');
```

To give it a try first and be sure it works try accessing `http://domaine2.com/books` to see if you get a json with your books.

Comment: Helo thank you for your reply , but with this case anyone can get content from my website , i don't want that , i want only domain1 to rceive data

Comment: You can use laravel-cors. Try this: http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/      Remember this is where you pu your url `->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'domain1')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should use API. Although it will not be that easy, because you want to create cross-domain requests.

If data you want to pass is not classified, you can make a public API handler, meaning that everyone will be allowed to access this. This can be for example a get request that return some objects from your database. Let's say you create a route in your domain1.com:

`GET domain1.com/api/books` that returns `json/data`

Then if anyone visits http://domain1.com/api/books he will see this response formatted in json. You can utilize it in your `domain2.com` app using CURL or built in vue.js with axios.

If data you want to provide is classified or you want to make requests other than GET (POST for example) you will have to read about application authorization. Putting in a simple way: you will have to show your `domain1.com` app that someone who wants to access restricted data is allowed to do it.

By the way, mentioning other response: you should utilize `api.php`, not `web.php` in routes. And have in mind that `file_get_contents` is significantly slower than CURL.

Comment: Helo thank you for your reply , i understand that i should use API , but i don't want evryone to access to this API , because it have a sensive information , i want Only domain1 that's can access to data ?